# Using a php code in a variable with multiple line strings

Tags: php, html, css, string, heredoc

How to give the content of $topic_image to a variable like this at the source part?
The problem is here: --> `src="image/<?php echo $topi_image?>"` .

```
$display_content=<<<END_OF_TEXT
        <div>
        <img src="image/<?php echo $topic_image ?>" style="width:200px;height:150px;">
        <p style="float:left">$topic_pris</p>
        <p style="float:left">$topic_title</p>
        <p style="float:left">$topic_name</p>
        </div>
    END_OF_TEXT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heredoc expands variables itself. You don't need the whole `<?php echo $topic_image ?>`, just the variable:

```
$display_content=<<<END_OF_TEXT
    <div>
    <img src="image/${topic_image}" style="width:200px;height:150px;">
    <p style="float:left">$topic_pris</p>
    <p style="float:left">$topic_title</p>
    <p style="float:left">$topic_name</p>
    </div>
END_OF_TEXT;
```

Comment: How can I use a function in this variable? I mean here:---> $display_content=<<<END_OF_TEXT <p>number_format($topic_pris)</p> END_OF_TEXT;